# Can't generate void methods for jersey client from wadl

Tags: rest, jersey, void, wadl

I'm using jersey.
I've got rest-method:

```
@PUT
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("/create-profile")
public void createProfile (Profile profile) throws UnableTransferToEntity {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try{
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(EntityConversionUtils.transformReporterProfileToSimpleProfileEntity(profile));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }finally{
        em.close();
    }
}
```

The part of wadl generated for this method:

```
<resource path="/create-profile">
            <method id="createProfile" name="PUT">
                <request>
                    <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
                </request>
            </method>
        </resource>
```

I'm using maven-plugin to generate a client:

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.ws.wadl</groupId>
            <artifactId>wadl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

The problem is that no void methods (putApplicationXml **Asvoid** ) are generated, only methods that expect response. When I try to use them even with Void.class expected I catch exception (returned a response status of 204 No Content).

If the rest method contains @QueryParam:

```
@DELETE
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Path("/remove-profile")
public void removeProfile (@QueryParam("id") final int id){
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    SimpleProfileEntity simpleProfileEntity = em.find(SimpleProfileEntity.class, id);

    new NotificationService().removeProfile(simpleProfileEntity.getNotificationProfile().getId());

    try{
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(simpleProfileEntity);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }finally{
        em.close();
    }
}
```

then wadl looks like:

```
<resource path="/remove-profile">
            <method id="removeProfile" name="DELETE">
                <request>
                    <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="id" style="query" type="xs:int"/>
                </request>
            </method>
        </resource>
```

As you can see it contains "param" node. 
The void client method for this entry is generated well.

How can I generate void method for my CreateProfile?

Answer (score 0):

The response type 205 is correct.

I run in the same problem and it seams that it is a problem of the client part, but not the server part.

I used `resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(String.class, datenJson);` and get the same exceptions.

It worked after removing the expected return type (first paremter of `put` (String.class)):

```
resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(datenJson);
```

*So do not specify an expected response type if you do not have any response.*